# I want to install two ionic app into my phone but firstly installed ionic app override by second ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk, ionic3

I have developed two ionic application using ionic 3 and I want install this two app into to my `android` phone separately, but when I installed one ionic app and going to install second app into my mobile phone (Android Phone) it remove the firstly installed ionic app installed second app
I tried changing `apk` name but not working.

apk file names

- (android-debug.apk )
- (android-debugtwo.apk)

App Name in *appconfig.xml*

```
 - <name>App1</name>
 - <name>App2</name>
```

Comment: change app package name.

Comment: could u please tell me how to do that

Comment: run first time app with actual package name, now on second time change the package name of your app that will create separate app in device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change widget id in **config.xml**

from something like

```
<widget id="io.ionic.starter"...
```

to

```
<widget id="android.debugtwo.App2"...
```

Answer (score 1):

Android OS differentiate the apps with the package names. if you are installing the app with same package name the previously installed app with be replaced/updated
In ionic you can change the Widget ID to make different app

```
<widget id="com.you.app1" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

and

```
     <widget id="com.you.app2" version="0.0.1" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
     xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```